# How to show that a process is not ergodic?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, self-learning, ergodic-theory, time-series

I'm trying to show that a certain process is not ergodic, but as I don't have much experience, I would first like to learn how to show simple cases.

We know that if a discrete stochastic process is i.i.d. so this is ergodic. So let's try to give an example of a stochastic process that is not independent to give an example of a stationary process that is not ergodic.

Let $X_t \sim Bernoulli(p)$ taking values $0$ or $1$ for all $t \geq 0$.

We say that $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is mean-ergodic if:
$$ \ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_t \overset{prob}{\rightarrow} p $$
Since the process is not independent, showing this I think gets a little more complicated. However, I would like to know how to show for this simple case and to know if there are other procedures to show non-ergodicity.

Comment: I've never read it but here's a paper with a procedure. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=179912

Comment: Nice paper. There's a lot I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it might help.

Comment: This should be quite easy if you just define $X_t=X_1$ for all $t$.  The general rule is to consider these easy extreme cases when you are doing counter-examples.  This extreme dependent case is much easier than the i.i.d. case.

Comment: Actually, I'm not very interested in counterexample, but in learning techniques to demonstrate that a certain stochastic process is ergodic. Can you tell me if there is any way to show ergodicity from its characteristic function (of finite dimensional vectors of the stochastic process) ?

Comment: Errata: I am interested in demostrate that some stochastic process (SP) is *not* ergodic. More specifically, I have a SP such that any finite dimensional vector has infinite divisibility distribution (ID). The characteristic function of an ID distribution is well characterized by the Lévy-Khintchine formula.